# Power of a relation and a equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

On a set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,12\}$ it is given a relation

$a\rho b\Leftrightarrow MOD(ab,a+b+1)=3.$

Is $\rho$ reflexive (R), symmetric (S) and  transitive (T)? Is $\rho^2$ R, S and T?

I know how to check is $\rho$ R, S and T. $\rho$ is not R because, for example, $1\not\rho1.$ $\rho$ is S and $\rho$ is not T ($2\rho 6$ and $6\rho 8$ but $2\not\rho 8$).

Is there any rule for $\rho^2$ to check if it is R, S and T, and more generally for $\rho^n$?

Comment: I am guessing that by R, S, and T you mean *reflexive*, *symmetric*, and *transitive*, respectively, but you really must write them out and not make the reader guess.

Comment: I wrote them out. Thanks!